# Remove checkbox selected from non-selected table row

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a kendo grid where the table row has a checkbox.  I have the selection of the `table tr` toggle the checkbox as well.  The problem I'm having is if I click a different row, I want to uncheck any other checkboxes that were checked.  I can remove the row highlight that I got from Kendo's website like:

```
var $row = $target.closest("tr");
var $selectedCheckbox = $row.find("input:checkbox");
var selectedClass = "k-state-selected";
$row.addClass(selectedClass).siblings().removeClass(selectedClass);
```

I thought I could do something similar for the checkboxes like:

```
    $row.addClass(selectedClass).siblings().removeClass(selectedClass).prop('checked', false);
or
$row.siblings("input.kendo-row-checkbox").prop('checked', false);
```

But those don't remove the checkboxes.   Is there a jquery way to do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you want, but what about use radio buttons ?

Just set all the radio button to the same `name`.

Simple [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/kelvinss/tmgJ9/).

Comment: Sorry the requirement is to use a checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

With the selector `:checked` you can select all checked boxes and with the method `.attr('checked', false)` you could uncheck these boxes.

Something like

```
$(':checked', $target.closest('tr')).attr('checked', false);
```